# Unknown issue with $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] returning false when it should be true

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

Hey there stackoverflow users, i have come upon a very confusing problem that I cant seem to move past. I am creating a forum type web page and am currently working on the comments section. I have a form that uses  the post method to send your comment as well as a hidden input to store the threads ID. I will post the entire php file below just to make sure nothing is left out.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $link);
  $threadID = $link['ID'];

  require("config.php");
  $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

  $error = mysqli_connect_error();
  if($error != null) {
      $output = "<p>Unable to connect to database!</p>";
      exit($output);
  } else {
      //Get Thread Data
      $query = "SELECT username, title, content FROM threads, users WHERE threads.ID = $threadID AND users.ID = threads.makerID;";
      $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

      //Get Comment Data
      $query = "SELECT username, comment FROM comments, users WHERE threadID = $threadID AND users.ID = comments.makerID;";
      $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <title>BodyweightMate</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styling.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!--Top masthead-->
<header class="masthead" id="top">
  <h1 class="masthead-title"> Welcome To BodyweightMate </h1>
</header>

<!--Navigation bar-->
<nav class="navbar">
  <table class="navbar-table">
    <tr>
      <!--Logo-->
      <td>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php">
          <img src="../images/logo.jpg" alt="BodyweightMate" height="30" width="30">
        </a>
      </td>

      <!--Login/Profile-->
      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { 
        echo"<td><a class=\"navbar-profile\" href=\"profile.php\"> Profile </a></td>";
        echo"<td><a class=\"navbar-logout\" href=\"logout.php\"> Logout </a></td>";
      } else {
        echo"<td><a class=\"navbar-login\" href=\"login.php\"> Login </a></td>";
      }?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</nav>

<!--Main portion-->

<section class="content-section">
  <article>
    <h3><?php echo $row['username']. ": " .$row['title']; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>

    <br> 

    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <p>Some annoying user: Gr8 B8 M8</p>
    <p>Annoying users friend: I R8 8/8</p>
  </article>
  <div>
    <!--If logged in, ability to comment-->
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])): ?>
      <form role="comment-form" method="POST" action="processcomment.php" id="mainForm">
        <input type="hidden" value="$threadID" name="threadID">

        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label for="comment">Comment </label> <br>
          <textarea class="comment-text" name="comment" rows="2" maxlength="255"></textarea>
        </div> <br>

        <input type="Submit" class="btn-newcomment" value="Submit Comment" name="submit">
      </form>
    <?php endif ?>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Right portion-->
<aside class="content-aside">
  <div>
    <!--If logged in, be able to create a thread-->
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        echo"<form method=\"post\" action=\"makethread.php\">";
        echo"<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn-newthread\" value=\"Create New Thread\" name=\"submit\">";
        echo"</form>";
      } 
    ?>
  </div>

  <!--Info-->
  <div>
    <p> GOING TO NEED A SEARCH FUNCTION HERE
    This is the cool little aside section. It will always be there to provide you with some very nice little details, helpful links, maybe a list of moderators? who knows! The uses are endless when you have a beautiful little aside like this one! Here are a few very useful bodyweight fitness links to get us started :D </p>
  </div>
  <br> 
  <div>
    <ul class="content-aside-links">
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness"> Reddit's Bodyweightfitness Forum </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine"> Reddit's Bodyweightfitness RR </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="http://antranik.org/bodyweight-training/"> Antranik's Bodyweightfitness Routine </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</aside>

<!--Footer -->
<footer class="footer">
  <div>
    <p>  Use of this site constitutes acceptance of our User Agreement &copy; 2017 BodyweightMate inc. All rights reserved. </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The error is occurring under the main portion where i check if a user is logged in, and if they are add a short form consisting of a message, a text area, and a submit button. This form sends the information to the following php file.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { header("location: main.php"); }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    require("config.php");
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
    if($error != null) {
        $output = "<p>Unable to connect to database!</p>";
        exit($output);
    } else {

        //Validation
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            $threadID = $_POST['threadID'];
            $user = $_SESSION['login_user'];
        } else {
            //Redirect back to register
            echo"<p>Form must use post or input was bypassed.</p>";
            echo"<a href=\"main.php\"> Return to home page. </a>";
            mysqli_close($connection);
            exit(); 
        }
```

There is no issue with connecting to the database, and I don't believe the remainder of the code is necessary to help me with this error since that one if statement of checking if the form is using post is failing and the else statement is always called. Why is this? i have rewritten the form multiple times ensuring that its properly structured and using post yet it fails every time!

Comment: check in the console if the form method is post

Comment: I did, console displays this <form role="comment-form" method="POST" action="processcomment.php" id="mainForm">

Comment: oh wait sorry, are you saying test by sending that information to the console?

Comment: @ZacGrafton like v Sugumar mentioned, check the network tab from chrome dev tool, check the request if it's really post request.

Comment: @Roljhon here is what it displayed http://imgur.com/a/8Cosg. Does that mean it is indeed not using post? i don't understand why it isn't though

Comment: @ZacGrafton it's a GET request that's why. hmmmm that's weird, something is overriding it.

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attack. You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for your queries to minimize this exposure. Also, you should be using SQL92 style joins (`from table a join table b on a.field = b.field`) over current method you're using for joining tables.

Comment: @Roljhon any idea what that is?

Comment: @alroc thanks for the tip, i use prepared statements when adding to the database but i didn't know it was necessary when pulling from it

Comment: @ZacGrafton it's necessary **any** time you interact with the database if there's user input involved. You cannot trust the user's input to be safe when concatenating it into a string **regardless* of whether it's a read or write.

Comment: @ZacGrafton pretty weird case, however, are you using `.htaccess` to manage requests to your server?

Comment: @alroc but in this case i am not taking user input, I am just pulling and displaying what is in the server correct? or am I understanding it wrong

Comment: @Roljhon I don't know what that is so I am going to say that no i do not :) However i have multiple other forms all coded the same way with the same validation and they are all working :/

Comment: @Roljhon the only thing in my config file is just your basic                      $host = "localhost";
 $database = "cosc360";
 $user = "root";
 $password = "";

Comment: @ZacGrafton `WHERE threads.ID = $threadID` - `$threadID` is coming from the client end (it comes in via the querystring), therefore it's input you can't trust to be safe. Really, just get in the habit of *always* using prepared statements and you'll be in much better shape. Don't selectively use them - eventually, you'll slip up and forget to use one where you're supposed to. Plus, consistency in how you write code is always good.

Comment: @alroc Oh I didn't even think of that, thank you very much!

Comment: @ZacGrafton try emptying your `action` form attribute, so it will request a POST just within the current page. And see again if the request method made is GET.

Comment: @Roljhon hey man thanks for all the advice you've given me. I gave up and move on to finish other things and when i went back to see if i could fix it again, it just started working out of nowhere even though i made no changes... so yeah that was no fun but at leas it works now! Sorry I couldn't leave you with an answer to this

Comment: @ZacGrafton well that's good to hear bro, just pretty a weird case, can't give you answers actually since there no specific answers to that, me myself haven't encountered that kind of issue since then, but if I were you to that point I already did an ajax on that :D and let javascript handle the request rather than the form itself. but anyway, maybe soon someone will answer this post :)